# unable to get ref of headless-ui controlled component using react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, headless-ui

We are using `headlessui` components (combobox) in our application along with `react-hook-form` . We are having hard time trying to figure out how to get `ref` of controlled component.

I setup a codesandbox to explain the issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-controller-forked-fr9dsn?file=/src/index.js

How to get `ref` of a controlled component ?